# Total Mean Curvature as a integral on the whole space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, geometric-measure-theory

It is well known from De Giorgi that we may express the surface area of a domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ as:

$$
\int_{\partial\Omega} 1\ d\sigma=\int_{\Omega} ||\nabla H(\phi(x))||\ dx=\int_{\Omega}\delta(\phi(x))|\nabla\phi(x)|\ dx.
$$

where $\Omega=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^N|\ \phi(x)>0\}$, $\phi:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, $H$ is the Heaviside function and $\delta$ is the Dirac function.

My question is if there is a formula for the total mean curvature as a integral on the whole $\Omega$. We know that the total mean curvature can be expressed as:

$$
\int_{\partial\Omega} k(x)\ d\sigma,\ k(x)=-\text{div}\left (\dfrac{\nabla\phi(x)}{|\nabla\phi(x)|}\right )
$$
so that we will have: $\int_{\partial\Omega} k(x)\ d\sigma=\int_{\Omega} F(\phi) \ dx$, where $F$ is some function.
The same question for the total Gaussian curvature.